# Why does this matrix dot product program print addresses in the last column in some cases?

Tags: c, matrix, printf, dot-product

I have written this program to find the dot product of two matrices. It works fine for several cases, but while I was testing I noticed that it printed what appear to be addresses in the last column and I cant figure out why. Specifically for the following input: 3 2 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 3 3 2 1

[image]

I am using CodeBlocks to compile and run the code. Also, I am relatively new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Method to allocate memory for a 2D array
int** allocateMatrix(int rows, int columns)
{
    //Declaration of variables
    int **matrix, i;

    //Allocate memory to store 'rows' many pointers to integers
    matrix = malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));

    //For-loop to allocate memory to store 'columns' many integers, and initialize them to zero
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = calloc(0,columns*sizeof(int));
    }

    return matrix;
}

int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    int n, m, p; //used as matrix dimensions
    int i, j, k; //used in for-loops

    //Read input
    do
    {
        //printf("Enter value of rows for first matrix (greater than 0):\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while(n<0);

    do
    {
        //printf("Enter value of columns for first and rows for second matrix (greater than 0):\n");
        scanf("%d", &m);
    }while(m<0);

    do
    {
        //printf("Enter value of columns for second matrix (greater than 0):\n");
        scanf("%d", &p);
    }while(p<0);

    //Create three matrices, by calling 'allocateMatrix' function
    int** matrix1 = allocateMatrix(n,m);
    int** matrix2 = allocateMatrix(m,p);
    int** matrix3 = allocateMatrix(n,p);

    //Two for-loops to store values in 'matrix1'
    //For-loop to go through rows
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //For-loop to go through columns
        for (j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            //Read input
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Two for-loops to store values in 'matrix2'
    //For-loop to go through rows
    for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        //For-loop to go through columns
        for (j=0; j<p; j++)
        {
            //Read input
            scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //THREE for-loops to multiply values in 'matrix1' and 'matrix2' and store results in 'matrix3'
    //For-loop to go through rows of 'matrix3' and 'matrix1'
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //For-loop to go through columns of 'matrix3' and 'matrix2'
        for (j=0; j<p; j++)
        {
            //For-loop to go through columns of 'matrix1' and rows of 'matrix2'
            for(k=0; k<m; k++)
            {
                //Read input
                matrix3[i][j] = matrix3[i][j] + (matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Print the resulting matrix
    //Two for-loops to print values in 'matrix3'
    //For-loop to go through rows
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //For-loop to go through columns
        for (j=0; j<p; j++)
        {
            if (j==p-1) //for correct format
            {
                printf("%d", matrix3[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d ", matrix3[i][j]);
            }
        }
        //Change line
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Free the memory up!!!!
    free(matrix1);
    free(matrix2);
    free(matrix3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to allocate your 2-D arrays the way you have, then you should also deallocate them similarly.  Right now you are only free'ing your row pointers.  You aren't freeing your column allocations. (Make sure your free your column allocations before you free the row pointers).

Comment: okay thanks! does the order in which I free them matter? would I have to free the columns first and then the rows?

Comment: Yes, the order matters, which is why I mentioned it.  If you free'd the rows first, then your pointers to the column allocations could become garbage (or accessing them could lead to a seg fault, etc.).  So, you have to free the column allocations before you free the array of row pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate any memory here:

```
matrix[i] = calloc(0,columns*sizeof(int));
```

The first parameter to calloc sets the number of elements you want to allocate. In this case it should be `columns`

```
matrix[i] = calloc(columns,sizeof(int));
```

Also made sure you validate your scanf input.

Comment: oh you're right, I thought I was initializing all the elements to 0 the way I wrote it, can't find where I saw that.. i changed it and it works now thanks! :) when you say validate my scanf input you mean when the numbers in the matrices are being read right?

Comment: @Yiannis Yes you have to check the input is within some required values.

Comment: btw i still only have rep of 10 so i cant vote up answers yet.. how can i get more rep? i have only asked about 3-4 questions so far.. @reader

Comment: @Yiannis You can accept answers that answered your questions. That green checkmark at the left side.